# java - collision detection not working?

Tags: java, collision

im quite new to java. I am trying to make it so that i can control a ball with the arrow keys and then if you collide with another ball, it will print a line in the console saying "you lost" or somthing.

I have done the moving, but i am struggling a bit with how i can get the 2 balls to collide. so far i have tried this (i think i put a rectangle around the ball, but i don't know really!):

```
public void collision() {
    Rectangle rectP = new Rectangle(player.x, player.y, player.WIDTH, player.HEIGHT);       
    Rectangle rectE = new Rectangle(Enemy.ex, Enemy.ey, Enemy.WIDTH, Enemy.HEIGHT);

    if(rectP.intersects(rectE))
    {

    System.out.println("game over");
    }
}
```

Could someone help me out and explain what i have done wrong.

ps. please don't just give me the code, i do want to try and learn!!!.

thanks.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    repaint();
    x += velx;
    y += vely;
}

public void up() {
    vely = -1.5;
    velx = 0;
}

public void down() {
    vely = 1.5;
    velx = 0;
}

public void left() {
    vely = 0;
    velx = -1.5;
}

public void right() {
    vely = 0;
    velx = 1.5;
}

public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    int code = e.getKeyCode();
    if (code == KeyEvent.VK_UP) {
        up();
    }
    if (code == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) {
        down();
    }
    if (code == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
        left();
    }
    if (code == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
        right();
    }
}
```

Comment: Probably should of said that when i run it and move the balls over each other, nothing happons.

Comment: How often are you running this `collision()` method? Is it set on a timer to run every second or few milliseconds?

Comment: no, how would i do that?

Comment: Just run `collision()` every time the balls move.

Comment: Can you show the implementation of intersects method?

Comment: Do you have the balls moving?  If so, show your `moveBall()` method

Comment: by the moveBall(), do you mean what i have just edited?

Comment: Im not really sure how to implement the intersects method, thats kind of what im asking, if thats what i need to do?

Comment: and clark when i ran collision() evry time the ball moves, the console got spammed by "game over"

Comment: Just check if the distance between the balls is less than the sum of the radii.

Answer (score 0):

If you have coords X and Y of the two ball centers and you know balls radiuses - this should be a simple task.

Just calculate the distance between centers of the balls and compare it with sum of balls radiuses.

You asked to skip formulas so that's it :)

PS What looks strange in your code is that `player` is lowercased but `Enemy` is capitalized.. is it a class or an object?

Comment: it's a class that i named wrongly and havent got round to fixing.

also, if you can do what you said, why is alot of people saying that i should use rectangles?

Comment: then why you read values `Enemy.ex` from the class? or it's not moving?

Comment: and one more. if it's a ball - why it has width and height?

Comment: how should i do it instead?

Comment: ball.radius , I guess :) and create an enemy object anyway, do not use static stuff if you do not know why you need it (technical need I mean)

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't think that what is wrong is the collision detection. I think that what is wrong is that what the computer think that the objects are somewhere else then where they actually are. Like one time when I was trying to make a brickbreaker paddle, I was having problems with collision detection when really the program thought that the paddle was on the opposite side! What you should do is that you should draw the positions of the rectangle onto the game. This way, you can see where the computer thinks the objects are. Maybe they are totally off?